# What's the best way to move background in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I need to create a moving illusion on canvas: user's object locates in a part of screen without moving but backround moves cyclically. It isn't a simple moving an image from one side to another. Image's moving depends on mouse coordinates.

So, questions:

What's the best way to do it? Use context.translate? 
What size for image is better? 3840×2160 is enough?

Thanks!

Comment: You won't need `translate` to change a background's position. Just  change the x,y coordinates of `drawImage`. To "move" something in a Canvas, you must 1. Clear the canvas using `clearRect`, 2. Redraw the image in its new position with `drawImage(yourBackground,x,y)`. If you need to animate the image you can use `requestAnimationFrame` to create an animation loop. We can't help with image size because you haven't explained enough about the illusion you're creating.

Comment: @markE Thank you for your answer!